# Rxjs subscription in constructor unwise

Tags: angular

I was told in a recent job interview that by placing a subscription in the constructor (for example to get a query param) was unwise as it can be intermittent as to when that value is available. Is that correct? I’ve personally done it in all my projects so far and have never had an issue with that.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Do you control when the constructor is called?

Comment: please share an example

Comment: I could think of a scenario which might be dangerous (not related to yours): if you use class inheritance, you should not call instance methods in your constructor because a subclasses might not have completed initializiation. Therefore, if your observable immediately yields elements upon subscription and if the configured scheduler is synchronous you might get into problems if your subscription callback invokes instance methods (many ifs!).

Comment: Even without using inheritance your component might have input parameters (@Input). Notice that they are not set at the time when the constructor gets invoked. If your subscription callback depends on them, you are on the safe side if you ensure that it gets invoked only when the components has been completely initialized, i.e. when ngOnInit got called.

Answer (score 1):

> was **unwise** as it can be intermittent as to when that value is available. Is that **correct**?

the real is answer is it depends from company-to-company.
a good practice in company X might be a bad practice in company Y(and vice versa)

most of the time **ngOnInit** is the correct place but that doesnt really apply to services. it doesnt really matter where you want to call .subscribe() as long as you are managing your subscriptions and able to .unsubscribe() to them when you need to. I myself avoid calling .subscribe() to my constructors, but that doesnt really warrant saying "your way is wrong".

Who decides which is wrong and right? The most important thing is consistency, if majority of you team codes it in the constructor, then you should code it in the constructor. if majority of your team says its wrong, then you follow them and avoid calling it in your constructor.